# Javascript - Decimal Number Mask

Tags: javascript, regex, frontend

I have an input that should just allow decimals values like 1000.20, 10.00. The decimal shouldn't be displayed more than to the hundredth decimal place.

First i need to clean any value that is not a number or a dot. 
I tried that follow regex but it just allow numbers:

```
    event.target.value = event.target.value.replace(/\D/g, '');
```

How can i do a mask for that?

Comment: Are you trying to make it so that the input forces the value to show 2 decimal places? Also, your example of `1000.200` would be out to the thousandths

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can slice the string counting two chars from the right and concatenate a dot to it.

Something like this

```
let number = event.target.value.replace(/\D/g, '');
event.target.value = number.slice(0,-2)+'.'+number.slice(-2);
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use a online regex tester in order to come up with an regex ;)
But a possible answer would be: `^/\d+(\.\d{1,3})?$/gm`
https://regex101.com/r/UnpNOG/1